# Plot symbolically in mathematica

Tags: plotting

I want to know is it possible to plot symbolically ?
for example I need to plot this function symbolically(where a>0 and c>b and and b>0)

```
FourierTransform[((a Cos[2 c π x] Sin[b π x])/(π x))^5, x, f,FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

output

```
(1/(24576 π^4))a^5 (5 (f - 3 b π - 10 c π)^4 Sign[
     f - 3 b π - 10 c π] + 
   10 (f + b π - 10 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π - 10 c π] - 
   5 (f + 3 b π - 10 c π)^4 Sign[
     f + 3 b π - 10 c π] + (f - 5 b π + 
      10 c π)^4 Sign[-f + 5 b π - 10 c π] + (f + 
      5 b π - 10 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π - 10 c π] + 
   25 (f - 3 b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[f - 3 b π - 6 c π] + 
   50 (f + b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π - 6 c π] - 
   25 (f + 3 b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + 3 b π - 6 c π] + 
   5 (f + 5 b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π - 6 c π] + 
   50 (f - 3 b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[f - 3 b π - 2 c π] + 
   100 (f + b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π - 2 c π] - 
   50 (f + 3 b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + 3 b π - 2 c π] + 
   10 (f + 5 b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π - 2 c π] - 
   10 (f - 5 b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f - 5 b π + 2 c π] + 
   50 (f - 3 b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f - 3 b π + 2 c π] - 
   100 (f - b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f - b π + 2 c π] + 
   100 (f - b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[-f + b π + 2 c π] + 
   100 (f + b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π + 2 c π] - 
   50 (f + 3 b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + 3 b π + 2 c π] + 
   10 (f - 5 b π - 2 c π)^4 Sign[-f + 5 b π + 
      2 c π] + 
   10 (f + 5 b π + 2 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π + 2 c π] - 
   5 (f - 5 b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f - 5 b π + 6 c π] + 
   25 (f - 3 b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f - 3 b π + 6 c π] - 
   50 (f - b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f - b π + 6 c π] + 
   50 (f - b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[-f + b π + 6 c π] + 
   50 (f + b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π + 6 c π] - 
   25 (f + 3 b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + 3 b π + 6 c π] + 
   5 (f - 5 b π - 6 c π)^4 Sign[-f + 5 b π + 6 c π] + 
   5 (f + 5 b π + 6 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π + 6 c π] + 
   5 (f - 3 b π + 10 c π)^4 Sign[
     f - 3 b π + 10 c π] - 
   10 (f - b π + 10 c π)^4 Sign[f - b π + 10 c π] + 
   10 (f - b π - 10 c π)^4 Sign[-f + b π + 10 c π] + 
   10 (f + b π + 10 c π)^4 Sign[f + b π + 10 c π] - 
   5 (f + 3 b π + 10 c π)^4 Sign[
     f + 3 b π + 10 c π] + (f - 5 b π - 
      10 c π)^4 Sign[-f + 5 b π + 10 c π] + (f + 
      5 b π + 10 c π)^4 Sign[f + 5 b π + 10 c π])
```

if not , how can plot this function from -100 < f < 100 with definite a,b,c value.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot symbolically"? Can you give a simple example of plotting something symbolically?

Comment: it means constant variable are indefinite and we plot the diagram without any numbers or values . For example here all constant are are indefinite http://obrazki.elektroda.pl/2659218100_1476433284.png but we can plot it

Comment: I would say that it is not a plot, but a schematic view, right. Or a sketch? I know nothing about the existence of a function for that in Mma. On the other hand you might fix numerical values for parameters, plot the function, and then remove the ticks and place there notations you want.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation . would it possible tell me how can plot FourierTransform[((a Cos[2 c π x] Sin[b π x])/(π x))^5, x,f,FourierParameters -> {1, -1}] for  -100 < f < 100 with definite a,b,c value.I did something with plot function but I was unsuccessful .

Comment: Have a look at Menu/WolframDocumentation/Plot

Comment: Thank you for your response. but as I Plot my output it has given me a wrong answer.what is my miskate?
x[k_] := FourierTransform[(20 ( 
    Cos[2 20* \[Pi] x] Sin[3* \[Pi] x])/(\[Pi] x)), x, f, 
  FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]      Plot[x[k], {f, -100, 100}]

Comment: You have numerous syntax errors, for example `[Pi]` and others. You should remove it. I vote to close this question because of the elementary errors causing the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46798/discussion-between-ehsan-zakeri-and-alexei-boulbitch).